# How to finding a directly connected neighbour in 2D matrix?

Tags: c++, math, matrix, 2d, formula

In a 2D matrix I want to find a single directly connected neighbor by its ID respectively direction.

What I mean:
x0 = x
y0 = y - 1
x1 = x + 1
y1 = y
x2 = x 
y2 = y + 1
x3 = x - 1
y3 = y

or as an graphic:

```
        ╔═══════╗
        ║   N   ║
        ║ x,y-1 ║
        ║       ║
╔═══════╬═══════╬═══════╗
║   W   ║       ║   E   ║
║ x-1,y ║  x,y  ║ x+1,y ║
║       ║       ║       ║
╚═══════╬═══════╬═══════╝
        ║   S   ║
        ║ x,y+1 ║
        ║       ║
        ╚═══════╝
```

Some years ago as I started programming I had the same problem and solved it with an ugly switch-case which could be highly improved:

```
if (mode == 'Y'){

    switch(direction){
        case 1:
            return -1;
        case 2:
            return 0;
        case 3:
            return 1;
        case 4:
            return 0;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

if (mode == 'X'){

    switch(direction){
        case 1:
            return 0;
        case 2:
            return 1;
        case 3:
            return 0;
        case 4:
            return -1;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

A cell should be accessible by a single formula with x,y and the direction (N,E,S,W e.g. 0-3)

I don’t want to have all neighbors, like defining the space around it (x-1,y-1 to x+1,y+1). This would be kind a simple by just iterating threw the square. I just want a single cell.

That’s sound kind a simple but giving me headaches in finding a short, fast and legit solution. Preferred Language is C++

I'm excited about your solutions!

**EDIT**

I figured out the problem now.

Take a look at this: [Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyyP8.png)

Sadly im yet not allowed to post images but as you can see the intersection of the graph with the constants representing  the direction is exactly what have to be added to x coordinate as you can see above

This means, that we can use a simple Sine wave for getting y and from this the formulas are:

```
x1 = x + cos((2*pi*(dir-1))/4)
y1 = y + cos((2*pi*(dir-2))/4)
```

While `dir` is from 0 to 3

Thats my solution in finding a pure mathematical way of calculation the connected neighbours. Of course this could be aproved in some way?

Thanks for your solutions! Looking forward to see your solutions for this problem!

Cheers!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, explain the problem that you have in the present solution and what you'd consider a "proper" solution.

Comment: Off topic: "A cell should be accessible by a single formula with x,y and the direction (N,E,S,W e.g. 0-3)" recommend using an `enum` to replace the numeric 0..3 with nice, easy to read names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using an array? For example,

```
int goY[] = {-1,0,1,0};    
int goX[] = {0,1,0,-1};

x += goX[direction];
y += goY[direction];
```

or incorporating `mode`

```
int move[2][4] = 
{
    {-1,0,1,0},    
    {0,1,0,-1}
};
```

Your code could look like:

```
loc += move[mode - 'x'][direction];
```

but I suspect you can do away with `mode` entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve it with two "for-loops"

For Example:

```
for (cx = -1; cx <= 1; cx++) {
    for (cy = -1; cy <= 1; cy++) {
        // All neighbors (N, NE, E, SE, S, SW, W, NW)
        if (1 == abs(cx - cy)) {
            // directneighbors (N, E, S, W)
        }
    }
}
```